# Why my laptop sound goes down while plugged in or battery saver is off?

Tags: laptop, audio, acer-aspire, audio-output

My laptop has a fairly loud sound while battery saver mode is enabled,but I don't understand why the sound goes down when I plug in the laptop or turn off the battery saver.Is there any fix to this or it is a feature of the laptop itself?Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a software problem..not hardware..ANYONE FACING THIS ISSUE IN FUTURE..I WOULD RECOMMEND YOU TO DO A CLEAN INSTALL OF WINDOWS AND CHECK FOR REGISTRY ERRRORS..I GAINED THE KNOWLEDGE PURELY ON HAND ON EXPERIENCE BASIS.